# My datagridview shows a row but there are no data

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that shows data from a sqlserver. In case I use a filter that there are no data... in my datagridview an empty row is shown. I have a button in which I call a method that recharge data. If I click it, no data is shown.
I don't understand why if I click this button, no data appears. But if I call the same method the button call, the empty row appears.

I have tried with datagridview.rows.clear(), invalidate() and update()...
and rows.count is 0

Thanks!

Comment: Show your full code..

Comment: @SonerGönül I have tried with rows.cler(), invalidate() and update().

Answer (score 1):

I think you must set this property to avoid users to adding new row to `DataGridView`.

```
DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Comment: What is your datasource DataType?

Comment: I write in every row/cell the data  I get from a sql query with a reader

Comment: Why do not use the `BindingSource` or `DataTable`?

Comment: Because I have to do some checks with the data I have in the db

Comment: So you can after validate and checking data in data reader, add them to a `DataTable` or `List`. Then add this object to datasource of datagridview. That is not better?